# Sistema de solicitudes

Tags: php, mysqli

Estoy haciendo la parte del perfil donde puede mandar, recivir y eliminar. Tengo el siguiente problema es que cuando miro el resultado me sale para mandar solicitud.
Este es el siguiente código:

```
<?php
  $my_user = db_exec('fetch_assoc', db_exec('query',"SELECT * FROM friends WHERE (transmitter = '{$my_data['id']}') OR (receiver = '{$my_data['id']}')"));
  $query_  = db_exec('fetch_assoc', db_exec('query',"SELECT * FROM friends WHERE (transmitter = '{$user['id']}' AND receiver = '{$my_data['id']}') OR (transmitter = '{$my_data['id']}' AND receiver = '{$user['id']}')"));
?>
<?php if ($my_data['id'] == $user['id']) { ?>
<div class="profile-header-info-actions">
  <p class="profile-header-info-action button primary">Pasarte a pro</p>
</div>
<?php } elseif ($my_data['id'] != $user['id']) { ?>
<div class="profile-header-info-actions">
  <p class="profile-header-info-action button secondary"><span class="hide-text-mobile">Envíar</span> solicitud +</p>
  <p class="profile-header-info-action button primary"><span class="hide-text-mobile">Envíar</span> mensaje</p>
</div>
<?php } elseif ($my_data['id'] == $my_user && $query_['status'] == '0') { ?>
<div class="profile-header-info-actions">
  <p class="profile-header-info-action button secondary"><span class="hide-text-mobile">Anular</span> solicitud -</p>
  <p class="profile-header-info-action button primary">Enviar mensaje</p>
</div>
<?php } elseif ($my_data['id'] != $user['id'] && $query_['status'] == '0') { ?>
<div class="profile-header-info-actions">
  <p class="profile-header-info-action button secondary"><span class="hide-text-mobile">Aceptar</span> solicitud +</p>
  <p class="profile-header-info-action button primary"><span class="hide-text-mobile">Rechazar</span> solicitud</p>
</div>
<?php } elseif ($my_data['id'] != $user['id'] && $query_['status'] == '1') { ?>
<div class="profile-header-info-actions">
  <p class="profile-header-info-action button secondary">Eliminar amigo</p>
  <p class="profile-header-info-action button primary">Enviar mensaje</p>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Este es donde se obtiene el id del usuario del perfil:

```
$get_nick = $Core->setSecure($_GET['username']);
$profi    = new perfil();
$user     = $profi->get_datos($get_nick);

function get_datos($nick){
  global $Core;
  $nickx = $Core->setSecure($nick);
  $query_ = db_exec('query',"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$nickx."' LIMIT 1");
  if (db_exec('num_rows', $query_) > 0) {
    $datos = db_exec('fetch_assoc', $query_);
  } else $datos = 0;
  return $datos;
}
```

Este es donde obtengo el id actual del usuario:

```
if (@trim($id_user)) {
$query_ = db_exec('query',"SELECT u.*, r.* FROM users AS u LEFT JOIN ranges AS r ON r.type = u.rank WHERE u.email = '{$email}'");
if (db_exec('num_rows', $query_) == 0) {
  $connected = false;
  session_destroy();
} else {
  $my_data = db_exec('fetch_assoc', $query_);
  if ($my_data['ban'] == 1 OR $my_data['active'] == 'no') {
    $connected = false;
    session_destroy();
  } else {
    $connected = true;
    $admin = ($my_data['rank'] == 1 ? true : false);
    $moder = ($my_data['rank'] == 2 ? true : false);
  }
}
} else {
$connected = false;
session_destroy();
}
```

No creo que sea necesario explicar que es el "`$user['id']`" y "`$my_data['id']`".
La función db_exec() es para hace las busqueda mas facil en mysqli.

Comment: Si la solicitud ya fue enviada y te sigue apareciendo el enlace `Enviar solicitud`, entonces te falta agregar esa verificación en el primer `elseif`

Comment: Ni siquiera el usuario actual e a enviado la solicitud a dicho usuario. El problema se presanta es cuando está mirando su propio perfil.

Comment: El problema es que solo estás comparando `id`, cuando deberías comparar `id` de usuario actual contra `transmitter` o `receiver`, según sea el caso.

Comment: ¿Podrias darme un ejemplo breve?. Gracias.

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega el código donde obtienes `$my_data` y `$user`, probablemente desde ahí viene el problema.

Comment: Ya lo actualice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El primer paso es crear una variable para saber si se trata del mismo usuario. Luego, no tiene sentido crear `$my_user`, porque no estás creando un listado de amigos.

Es suficiente con una sola consulta donde el emisor/receptor puedan ser solo los usuarios involucrados (sesión y perfil), a esta consulta la llamamos `$amistad` y es la que se usará para las comparaciones, revisa los comentarios para más información.

```
<?php
  // Saber si el perfil es del mismo usuario
  $mismo = ($my_data['id'] == $user['id']) ? true : false;

  if($mismo) {
      // No es necesario ejecutar la consulta
      $amistad = false;
  } else {
    // Solo es necesaria una consulta y supongo que devuelve falso si no hay resultados
    $amistad  = db_exec('fetch_assoc', db_exec('query',"SELECT * FROM friends WHERE (transmitter = '{$user['id']}' AND receiver = '{$my_data['id']}') OR (transmitter = '{$my_data['id']}' AND receiver = '{$user['id']}')"));
  }
?>
<?php if ($mismo) { // No puede haber amistad consigo mismo ni enviar mensaje LOL ?>
<div class="profile-header-info-actions">
  <p class="profile-header-info-action button primary">Pasarte a pro</p>
</div>
<?php } elseif ($amistad === false) { // No se ha enviado solicitud ?>
<div class="profile-header-info-actions">
  <p class="profile-header-info-action button secondary"><span class="hide-text-mobile">Envíar</span> solicitud +</p>
  <p class="profile-header-info-action button primary"><span class="hide-text-mobile">Envíar</span> mensaje</p>
</div>
<?php } elseif ($my_data['id'] == $amistad['transmitter'] && $amistad['status'] == '0') {  // El usuario actual envió y no ha sido aceptada ?>
<div class="profile-header-info-actions">
  <p class="profile-header-info-action button secondary"><span class="hide-text-mobile">Anular</span> solicitud -</p>
  <p class="profile-header-info-action button primary">Enviar mensaje</p>
</div>
<?php } elseif ($my_data['id'] == $amistad['receiver'] && $amistad['status'] == '0') { // El usuario actual recibió la solicitud y no la ha aceptado ?>
<div class="profile-header-info-actions">
  <p class="profile-header-info-action button secondary"><span class="hide-text-mobile">Aceptar</span> solicitud +</p>
  <p class="profile-header-info-action button primary"><span class="hide-text-mobile">Rechazar</span> solicitud</p>
</div>
<?php } elseif ($amistad['status'] == '1') { // No importa quién recibió o envió, cualquiera de los dos puede eliminar la amistad ?>
<div class="profile-header-info-actions">
  <p class="profile-header-info-action button secondary">Eliminar amigo</p>
  <p class="profile-header-info-action button primary">Enviar mensaje</p>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Nada mal, pero no me muestra ningun resultado.

Comment: Perdona. El código esta bien y funciona. Era un error mio en obtener el id del usuario actual porque entraba en conficto con las dis bases de datos que tienen el mismo nombre para las ids.